# Unix du with progress

Tags: bash, shell, find, progress, du

I'm doing a normal `du` on some huge directory.  It probably takes ages as the storage also is network attached.

I would like to see the progress before the end of the process so that I can already estimate what's going on.  At any given time I'd like to see the already collected sum of disk usage as `du` counts it.  I found no option for `du` to provide this.  Did I miss something?  Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I imagined something like this:

```
du -ba . | { s=0; while read a b; do ((s+=a)); echo $s; done; }
```

This would sum up the output but of course this would sum up also the accumulated directory sizes (effectively multiplying the counted sizes).  I found no option to just mention the *files* in the output.  On the other hand, using `find -type f -printf "%s %p\n"` instead would count hardlinks multiple times.

Is there any typical tool to achieve what I want or a simple fix to the presented script?  Currently I consider writing a Python script for this but have the feeling that might be overkill.

Comment: You can use some of the tools that serve the purpose of displaying the disk usage. I think some of them have some kind of progress meter. But the only  way to have this meter properly working is by getting first the list of files and using it to gauge the progress when querying for the size. And probably, getting the list of files will take a similar time as gettting also the file size so...

Comment: @Poshi Walking through the file tree is taking ages and will probably not finish before I lose patience.  That's why I want to have some output before this is finished.

Comment: The point is that you cannot have a percentage of the total done if you don't know how much is the total. The only thing you can have is how many files have been processed (which is what the Ashish Singh answer is providing), but if you don't know haw many of them have to be processed, then you are as lost as before: you won't know how long will it take to finish.

Comment: @Poshi I don't need a percentage.  I'm not asking for a prognosis how long it will take.  I just want progress information.  The numbers can be absolute of course.  I expect to abort the process before it finishes.  But I'd like to see how many files and bytes it counted (excluding hardlinks) before I abort it.

Comment: Oh! In that case, you already have a couple nice solutions down :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that in order to profit from the performance of the `du` utility vs. any custom script, one could just:

1. download current core utils source from, e.g., https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.30.tar.xz
2. `tar -xf coreutils-8.30.tar.xz && cd coreutils-8.30`
3. `./configure --prefix=/custom/location/of/modified/coreutils`
4. in `./src/du.c` add after line `666` the statement `print_size (&tot_dui, _("total"));`

The end of the `process_file` function would look like:

```
  if ((IS_DIR_TYPE (info) && level <= max_depth)
      || (opt_all && level <= max_depth)
      || level == 0)
    {
      /* Print or elide this entry according to the --threshold option.  */
      uintmax_t v = opt_inodes ? dui_to_print.inodes : dui_to_print.size;
      if (opt_threshold < 0
          ? v <= -opt_threshold
          : v >= opt_threshold)
        print_size (&dui_to_print, file);

      print_size (&tot_dui, _("total")); /* extra statement */
    }

  return ok;
```

5. `make install`

This would make the modified `du` to report the total size after each file, i.e., the output could look like:

```
129K    ./bin/dirname
33M total
132K    ./bin/uname
33M total
207K    ./bin/sha1sum
33M total
156K    ./bin/truncate
33M total
311K    ./bin/pr
34M total
172K    ./bin/printf
34M total
138K    ./bin/pathchk
34M total
```

Comment: Yeah, I like that approach, unfortunately I'm on a server system where I'm not supposed to install my own stuff.  I might get along by saying, please, install me tool xyz, though.  But on the other hand this isn't far off writing the thing in Python.

Comment: @Alfe you could compile it and "install" in your home directory (as a custom "private" tool) so that it doesn't interfere with anything else (i.e., no root account needed), but a Python script would be probably indeed more "portable"... :)

Comment: Of course.  I might lack the compiler (libs, includes, whatever) on the target host, though, and I might not be able to cross-compile it from my local computer to the server.  But as I said, it's a nice approach to just patch my needs into `du` so solve the issue.  It's nothing I can tell others to do, though, so I'd prefer a script solution or the like.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a small bash one-liner to solve my issue.  It's not as nice as using `du` properly but it give progress information and it doesn't count hardlinks twice.

I give it here in one line and spread out to make it clearer:

```
find -type f -printf "%s %i %p\n" | { sum=0; declare -A inodes; while read size inode path; do [ "${inodes[$inode]}" != 1 ] && { inodes[$inode]=1; ((sum+=size)); echo "$sum $size $path"; }; done; }
```

And the same nicely formatted:

```
find -type f -printf "%s %i %p\n" | {
  sum=0
  declare -A inodes
  while read size inode path
  do
    [ "${inodes[$inode]}" != 1 ] && {
      inodes[$inode]=1
      ((sum+=size))
      echo "$sum $size $path"
    }
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below command give you a hint to progress ahead

`ls -laR | awk '{ total += $6;if(FNR%1000 == 0)print total;}; END { print total }'`

In the awk statement, you can various condition to check if it is a directory or links.

And `FNR%1000` will print the size progress every hundred line it reads. Instead of `ls`, you can use `find`

Comment: That sound a lot like the `find` version I proposed and dismissed with the reason that it would count hardlinks multiple times.  Your solution does have this flaw as well, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can download it, [`ncdu`](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) is a nice program that does the same as du, but with a nice interface including how far your progress is.

On Debian, Ubuntu, etc, you can install it with

```
sudo apt install ncdu
```

Comment: doesnt show real info

Comment: @bfday During scanning it will show the size it scanned, and the number of items it scanned. If used as ncdu -1 it will print this to stderr instead of in a ncurses screen.

Comment: I've tested it and in my case it showed 2.1 GB on the folder which is 8.3 GB. Checked ,command line options and haven't found any solution. looks like smsing wrong with it

Comment: @bfday It shows the current count, you have to wait until the process is completed.